# How do I pass a html form variable to a perl script via AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, perl

I am trying to pass the html variable from the list menu to the perl script via `POST` but what happens is that the jQuery `ajax()` was able to execute the perl without including the value got from the `document.getElementById`. Here is my HTML code:

```html
<form id="form">
    <p id="survey">
        <label for="list"><b>Ran survey</b></label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="division">Please select division:</label>
            <select type="list" id="list" name="division">
                <option>--Select One--</option>
                <option value="DENVER">Denver</option>
                <option value="PHOENIX_SOUTHWEST">Phoenix-Southwest</option>
                <option value="PORTLAND">Portland</option>
                <option value="SOUTHERN_HOUSTON">Southern-Houston</option>
                <option value="NORCAL">Norcal</option>
                <option value="SEATTLE">Seattle</option>
                <option value="VONS_SoCal">Vons-Socal</option>
                <option value="EASTERN">Eastern</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p id="survey">
            <input type="submit" value="Ran Survey" onclick="surveyFunction();" />
        </p>
    </form>
```

```js
function surveyFunction() {
    var div = document.getElementById("list").value;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "possurv.pl",
        data: div,
        success: function(result){
            $('#survfeedback').html(result);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: We need to see the relevant part of the Perl program or its documentation to answer this without guessing.

Comment: I'm surprised that this managed to execute the Perl, since the XHR request should be cancelled by the form submission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the parameter name in the querystring to assign the value to. I assume this should follow the standard practice of being the name of the control. In this case you can either build the  querystring yourself:

```
data: 'division=' + encodeURIComponent(div),
```

Or you can send an object and let jQuery serialise it to a querystring for you:

```
data: { division: div },
```

Comment: You forgot to apply `encodeURIComponent` to the user input for your manual attempt.

Comment: Who says the Perl program requires the input to be of the type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`? Could be it just checks the request body and doesn't expect a named parameter.

Comment: @simbabque — That would be an extremely odd edge case. Expecting the Perl to take application/x-www-form-urlencoded data is a reasonable assumption.

Comment: @Quentin I agree, but still, it's an assumption.  Rory kind of says that in his second sentence, which is good. Still I wanted to mention it since we cannot know without seeing the Perl code. :)

Comment: @Quentin good point about `encodeURIComponent`, thanks - answer updated.

Comment: Thanks. Including the parameter name in the query string worked.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.